# Remove particular id from database field

Tags: php, mysql

Am storing a string separated using `|`, which lists the groups allowed, now my issue is if I delete a group than I am not able to remove the ID from that particular field, for example

```
allowed_group_id
+---------------+
1332|4545|5646|7986
```

So for example am deleting the group say no 5646, so how do I alter the scripts and remove that particular group from the `allowed_group_id` in script table?

Comment: You have to fetch the record containing group id and remove the desired id 5646 from it and then again insert the new data into the field

Comment: You really should look at normalising the database. This issue would simply disappear. *Usually* (not always) delimited text in a database field is not a good thing.

Comment: You would be way better off if you normalize your database model and use a separate table for a one-to-many-relationship.

Comment: You should look at normalising your table so that `allowed_group_id` is in a lookup table `allowed_groups` with a link to the ID in the original table. Then you can `DELETE FROM allowed_groups WHERE group_id = 5646 AND foreign_id = ...`

Comment: Ok I understanding the thing but I need to provide multiple permissions to a single user so do you mean I should use insert for every permission I grant to the user?

Comment: because each user is having multiple group access

Comment: you can explode the string in array for '|' , and unset the array for value 5646, then implode it to string and save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend taking the entry, exploding it by "|", removing the appropriate entry, imploding it back and updating.

```
$allowedGroupId = '1332|4545|5646|7986';
$parts = explode('|', $allowedGroupId);
if(($key = array_search($deleteGroup, $allowedGroupId)) !== false) {
    unset($allowedGroupId[$key]);
}

$update = " ... "; //update with the new imploded values
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, not this but your comment helped :)

Comment: Ok, glad something helper :) Cheers

Comment: Ok pal your query failed when the field had single value with no separators so am trying this option now..lol

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

```
update table tableName set allowed_group_id = REPLACE(allowed_group_id, '5646', '');
```

Comment: wouldn't that leave the record like '1332|4545||7986'?

Comment: If you want to fix this, do the following: `UPDATE tableName SET allowed_group_id = REPLACE(REPLACE(allowed_group_id, '5646|', ''), '|5646', '');`

Answer (score 1):

Using Suresh response and improving it:

```
UPDATE TABLE tableName SET allowed_group_id = REPLACE(
    REPLACE(allowed_group_id, '5646', ''),
    '||',
    '|');
```

First you search for `'5646'` string in `allowed_group_id` and replace it with empty string `''`. Secondly you search and replace  two bars from your result `'||'` with only one bar `'|'`. This will avoid having `'1332|4545||7986'` in your `allowed_group_id`.

Comment: can you explain this a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Use explode:

```
$allowed_ids = explode('|', $current_allowed_group_ids);
if($remove_key = array_search($remove_id, $allowed_ids) !== false) {
    unset($allowed_ids[$remove_key]);
}
$update_query = 'UPDATE table_name SET allowed_group_id = "'. implode('|', $allowed_ids) .'" WHERE id= ...';
```

But you might want to alter your database design slightly, creating a pivot table to check for allowed ids. Example:

```
+------------+
|   GROUPS   |
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | grp_1 |
| 2  | grp_2 |
  ...

+--------------------+
|   ALLOWED_GROUPS   |
+--------------------+
| user_id | group_id |
+---------+----------+
|   2     |    1     |
|   2     |    2     |
|   5     |    2     |
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you should have a table with 2 columns 1 with the id of the action you whant to allow and one with the id of a group.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the other answers will solve your problem as-is: you might want to consider normalising your database.

For example, if you currently have a table `table_name` containing `id` and `allowed_group_id`, then you would create a new table `allowed_group` containing multiple rows for each allowed group:

```
foreign_id | group_id
-----------+---------
1          | 1332
1          | 4545
1          | 5646
1          | 7986
```

...and so on. Here, `foreign_id` is the ID of the row in your existing `table_name` table. Now, instead of your above problem, you can simply `DELETE FROM allowed_group WHERE foreign_id = 1 AND groupId = 5646`.

This is called putting your data in [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF).

Comment: Ok I understand bro, but the issue is each system has 100 scripts, each user needs to be customized that whether he can access that script, so if I simply put the script id's in the database, and it's done, so is that are ypu saying that for each person I need to put up 100rows? may be it can be more or less

Comment: Much better to have 100 rows in a lookup table than to have 100 IDs concatenated in a single field. It's also easy to insert multiple rows in 1 query: `INSERT INTO allowed_group VALUES (1, 1332), (1, 4545), ...`